Бесшовное обновление SPA
Какими методиками можно бесшовно обновить фронт SPA\PWA приложения?
У меня приложение на React и проблема в том, что при каждой заливке новой версии приходится перезагружать пользователей руками, а это усложняется тем, что есть ещё кеширование приложения (т.е. полный оффлайн режим), не говоря про адский DDoS сервака запросами.
И недавно у меня возник вопрос, а можно ли клиента обновить также, как делает это hot-update.json от dev версии react? Он способен обновить часть приложения без перезагрузки страницы! Это как раз то, что мне нужно, но я не понимаю, как мне это в своё приложение встроить?
Если у кого-то есть идеи или ссылки на доку/статьи по этой теме, то буду признателен, если поделитесь.
Стек: TypeScript, react-app-rewired, webpack, workbox

Hot reload - это глючная фигня. Не надо такое в проде использовать.
